# Is there any good calculus calculator with steps?

Tags: math

Is there any good calculus calculator with steps? Either online or not is fine. I know wolfram but it requires me to upgrade to Pro. Others like https://www.integral-calculator.com can't deal with complex ones. Any recommendations? Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Consider to define more precisely your expression "calculus calculator." It's been a few decades since I took calculus, but math of any form is universal. Calculus calculations are, in my opinion, defined mathematical calculations specific to a task, not something one would find in a turnkey package.

Answer (score 1):

If you can program in RPN on an HP programmable calculator, you have no real limitations. [RLM Software](https://rlmtools.com/) provides non-graphing versions of popular HP programmable calculators which includes the scientific version HP-11C. Another site, [PG Calculator](http://pgcalc.net/#/) also has an RPN/Algebraic programmable graphing version.

I purchased the HP calculator for both iOS and for Windows, but have not pursued the PG 6 from the latter link.

Comment: Thank you for recommendation. Do they support calculus calculation?

Comment: The caveat here is that one has to be able to create appropriate RPN code to accomplish the objective. If one can create calculus calculation on paper, one can program the software to perform the same steps. If you're looking for a plug-and-go solution, I don't think you'll find one.

Answer (score 1):

If you own an Ipad Wolfram Pro is only 5 Dollar for a lifelong usage.
At least when i studied 4 years back.